# aiboデベロッパープログラムを用いた連携アプリの一般公開について

Tags: aibo-developer

[QA](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60813/%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6) に記載の下記内容についての質問です。

> Q : 一般のaiboオーナー様向けの連携アプリケーションを公開できますか？
>   A : aiboとの連携サービスを一般に公開する仕組みは今後対応予定です。
>   ご希望の方は個別にお問合せください。

この連携アプリケーションとは、
aiboデベロッパープログラムにて作成したふるまい単体(例えば歩いた後にお座りするふるまい)でも公開できるのでしょうか?
上記に加え、Twitterなど他のアプリと連携させたふるまいを指しているのでしょうか?

また、個別に問い合わせくださいとありますが、
ユーザーが自由に投稿できるようなサイトが用意されるのではなく、
作成者から一度ソニーへ提出し、審査後に公開してもらえる様な仕組みになるのでしょうか?

Comment: スタックオーバーフローのプログラマ向けの質問からは外れていて、どちらかというとaiboの仕様、プロダクトの方針の質問かと思います。[どのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Sony側に問い合わせをしたほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: 「技術的な質問は Stack Overflowに投稿してください」とありますが、この質問はちょっと違うかと。
 http://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact

Comment: こちらで質問する前にaiboオーナーサポートへ問い合わせた所、
Stack Overflowで相談するように案内がありました。

経緯を書かずに誤解を与えてしまった点は申し訳ありません。

aibo デベロッパーサポートチームの方へ
やはりaiboオーナーサポートへ問い合わせるべき内容ということであれば、その旨お知らせください。

Comment: @Eva さん経緯の共有ありがとうございます。きちんとやり取りをして質問しているのですね。質問はクローズされた場合はやはり直接的にSonyとやり取りをせざる負えないと思います。ヘルプページと当コミュニティの使い方については[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)にいくつか注意事項がありますので、企業さんが見てくれているとありがたいのですが、、、

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

大変恐れ入りますが、技術的な質問以外につきましては、aiboオーナーサポートにお問合せください。
http://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html

今回は、すでにaiboオーナーサポートにお問合せいただいているということで、ご不便をおかけしてしまい誠に申し訳ございません。

担当に申し伝えましたので、改めましてaiboオーナーサポートよりお問合せいただけますと幸いです。
また、その際に今回の経緯をお伝えいただけますとスムーズにご案内させていただくことが可能です。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム